# SharePoint Online Workflow With Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, visual-studio

I'm trying to learn do build workflows for SharePoint online with Visual Studio. I've been following a PluralSight training session and understand the concepts and can make all the various demos work.

I can't seem to cross the bridge to applying it to the SharePoint site we've setup, though.

I just cruzed through a different tutorial and realized that maybe something is just missing. If I create a new solution and point it to my SharePoint site, when I create a workflow, shouldn't the site's lists and libraries be availalbe in the dropdown of options to associate the workflow to? They're not and that confuses me. I mean, I don't want to create a new one (like the Pluralsight training does). I want to apply it to an existing library.

Am I just not understanding? Or, am I missing some kind of connector that should make my site's lists and libraries availalbe in that dropdown?

Thanks,
Quintin